# Generating corresponding plain text from a encrypted password in mysql

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords, password-recovery

I somehow could not remember the password for a 'mysql' user. I want to identify the password rather than recovering the password.

Since the password is stored in mysql table in encrypted format , is there any way so that I can generate the corresponding plain text from the encrypted password.

Comment: First of all, you will need to know how it was encrypted before even trying to decrypt. Most CMS today use MD5, some of them have a salt (A combination which will be added to your password, for example salt: a1$ , password: Pass , Password that will be encrypted: a1$Passa1$ ) this hardens the process. With MD5, you can only try to decrypt using BruteForce or Rainbowtables (there are a few sites which will check rainbowtables, check google)

Answer (score 1):

[mysql stores user passwords hashed](http://www.palominodb.com/blog/2011/12/04/hashing-algorithm-mysql-password)  with `SHA1(SHA1(password))`.

You can use a password cracker such as [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) in order to find the password that generated the hash. Depending on the password strength, this may take some time.